# file_put_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to import an excel sheet of about 100,000 rows into my database. I am using maatwebsite/excel library in Laravel.

whenever I try to upload the excel sheet, I get the error

```
file_put_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory
```

here is what my controller method looks like

```
public function importData(Request $request)
{
    try {
        Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->file('file'));
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Record Imported Successfully');
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

can someone please help out. thanks.

Comment: Please check [this](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/2722) thread and confirm it's no the same issue

Comment: Have you checked the MIME type that is assigned (server) to the file extension? Also make sure that `$request->file('file')` really is the file and not the parent folder or something like that.

Comment: It's because it is being passed a directory, as the error message says.

Comment: I think @porloscerrosΨ is correct. my first thoughts where the file may be to large to upload.